# Which of two distributions was sampled from?

Tags: probability

Suppose that I have two sets $A$ and $B$. each of which contains $N$ random variables.

Set $A$ has $N$ normal random variables all with the same mean $\hat{\mu}$ and variance $\hat{\sigma}$.

Set $B$ has $N$ normal random variables, all of which have different means $\mu_i$ (normally distributed around $\mu$ with variance $\sigma_{\hat{\mu}}$) and variances $\sigma_i$ (normally distributed around $\sigma$ with variance $\sigma_{\hat{\sigma}}$).

Now, I can't sample individual variables from $A$ or $B$ - instead, I can only sample all $N$ variables at once, and compare the obtained sample distributions of them (including summary statistics, etc.)

Question 1: It appears to me that the expected sample mean and sample variance of both $A$ and $B$ should be the same: is this true?

Question 2: If this is the case, is there a method I could use to figure out which set was which (assuming I didn't know)? Again, I can't sample from individuals in a given set, but I can re-do my resampling procedure. I feel like the answer should somehow depend on $\sigma_{\hat{\mu}}$ and $\sigma_{\hat{\sigma}}$, but I don't know how to get there.

Any help or direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For the first question:***

the expected value of the empirical mean is
$$
E\left[
\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
\right]
 = \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N E[X_i]
$$
For the sample A it is $\hat\mu$.

For the sample B it is
$$
\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N E[X_i] = 
\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N E[E[X_i | \mu_i]]
= E\left[\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N E[X_i | \mu_i]
\right] = 
E\left[\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i\right] = \hat\mu
$$
using the same computation as for A.

***For the second question:***

Let us try with the second moment:
$$
\text{var}\left[
\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
\right]
 = \frac 1{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \text{var}[X_i]
$$
For the case A:
this is $\frac{\hat\sigma^2}N$.

For the case B:
it is
$$
\frac 1{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \left(
\text{var}[E[X_i|\mu_i, \sigma_i]
+ E[\text{var}[X_i|\mu_i, \sigma_i]] \right)
= \frac 1{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \left(     \sigma_{\hat\mu}^2
                               + (\sigma_{\hat\sigma}^2 + \sigma^2) \right) = 
\frac 1N \left(     \sigma_{\hat\mu}^2
                      + \sigma_{\hat\sigma}^2  + \sigma^2     \right)
$$according to [the conditional variance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance).

So the sample B must be more scattered than the sample A.

Comment: This does not address the second part of question 1 (the sample variances), which is what I am more interested in. I've gotten as far as you give, so I'm looking for a little more. This is very much not a homework problem, btw.

Comment: @DannyW. is my edit more convincing?

Comment: Almost. I am confused though why does the variance of $B$ not converge to the variance of $A$ as $\sigma_{\hat{\mu}}$ and $\sigma_{\hat{\sigma}}$ go to zero?

Comment: @DannyW. this is now fixed. I forgot one last term.

Comment: Ok. This did answer the question. I was hoping to would generalize to the comparing $\sigma_{\hat{\mu}}$ to $\sigma_{\hat{\sigma}}$, but this does not appear to be the case. Do you have any insight into how that might be done?

Comment: I don't see what you mean...